# Github can't sync

Tags: github

I'm using a github Mac client to manage my repo and for sent pull requests to the repo I forked. In the last few days, I can't send pull requests, I only recieve this error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing
https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I have also tried to set SSH instead of HTTPS, but doing this, the Mac client can't contact the server... How can I fix this?

This is [the project I need](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms).

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms.git` worked for me. your question doesn't belong here, contact github support

Comment: Make sure it wasn't due to some of the interruptions reported in the last few days by GitHub itself: https://status.github.com/ (and https://twitter.com/#!/github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to update my git version.
Thanks to all!